# SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC required for iomprovider connections?

Tags: odbc, sas

I use a proprietary application that reads from SAS datasets using the SAS local database provider, and writes to them using a SAS iomprovider connection. At the moment, according to proc setinit, the server hosting this application only has SAS analytics pro, SAS/CONNECT and the SAS/ACCESS interface to ODBC modules installed. As far as I can tell, we don't use the interface to ODBC anywhere in our SAS codebase, so I am trying to find out whether this module is required in order to run the aforementioned application. I've already asked the developers, but they aren't sure.

Doe anyone know whether the iomprovider functionality is included as part of base SAS / SAS analytics pro, or whether I actually do need the interface to ODBC in this situation?

Is there a way to temporarily disable the SAS/ACCESS interface to ODBC module, so I can test whether the application in question still works without it? I would prefer to avoid uninstalling SAS completely and reinstalling it without the module just to test this, as we have a fairly complex configuration.

If all else fails, I still have the option of putting in a support request with SAS, but I thought I'd ask here first as I know that there are quite a few SAS experts around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need it.  The IOMProvider is part of either SAS Integration Technologies or CONNECT (I believe).  If it is SAS IT, then that is provided in your Analytics Pro package.  It's been a while since I dealt with SAS Packaging.

You can test by finding the dll for Access/ODBC and moving it to a different location (where SAS cannot find it).  On my machine this is in C:\Program Files\SASHome\x86\SASFoundation\9.3\access\sasexe.  I'm not sure which dll it is, so some trial and error will be needed.  Just make sure you put it back when you are done!

In the end, the easiest path would be to just submit a ticket with SAS Tech Support.  They are friendly and should be able to get you an answer in a few hours.

Comment: Thank you - I'll test this and see how I get on. If it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: +1 to asking SAS Tech Support, or even your SAS sales rep - both should be able to easily answer your question.  I'd start with the sales rep, as they're usually very fast and can direct you to tech support if they don't know.

Comment: knowing a number of SAS sales reps, they will ask their pre-sales SE, who will either know or will ask tech support.  And if the answer could result in you paying a lower licensing fee, you might not get an answer.  That's why I always ask TS first!